# Return a JS variable as text to send to google analytics

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Please excuse my syntax. Conceptually I get the idea, but I am not an expert by any means!

I have some google analytics code, on my .Master file for my website. The content of the site is dynamically generated, and I don't have access to that backend code.

I am trying to send an event to analytics.'

Basically, you can see what I am trying to accomplish here....

```
ga('send', 'event', $('[id^="Add_"]'), 'click', 'AddToCart');
```

it finds the id's of my add to cart buttons dynamically, and uses that to track the event....the only problem is that it doesn't send that as text to analytics, so in my reports it comes up blank, but in real-time I can see that it does register the clicks.

I want it to work similarly to the way I send page views for the dynamic content:

```
 ga('send', 'pageview', $(document).find("title").text());
```

That seems to be working fine, it sends the virtual URL to analytics as the page title which was dynamically generated.

I guess I may have to define a variable, then return that as text, and send that...but I just don't know the syntax or where to put it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log($('[id^="Add_"]')?` Also, can you post your markup?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after figuring out which button was clicked, you can send a textual representation of the button element in some way.

For example, you could try this:

```
var el = $('[id^="Add_"]')[0];
var elementAsString = el.tagName.toLowerCase() + '#' + el.id;

ga('send', 'event', elementAsString, 'click', 'AddToCart');
```

And then your GA report would show the element as something like "button#Add_123". You can add more identifying details as needed.

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

> To send an event, you pass the ga function the send command with the
>   event hit type
>
> ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'nav buttons', 4);
>
> Where:
>   button is the category
>   click is the action
>   nav buttons is the label
>   4 is the value

So if we dissect what you are sending

```
ga('send', 'event', $('[id^="Add_"]'), 'click', 'AddToCart');
$('[id^="Add_"]').toString() which returns "[object Object]" is the category
click is the label
AddToCart is the value
```

The description of `Value` is

```
Values must be non-negative. Useful to pass counts (e.g. 4 times)
```

Since the string "AddToCard" is not a Number your value is blank

What I think you are looking to do is for every add button clicked you want to send a ga event

```
$('[id^="Add_"]').on('click',function(){
    /*
     *This is where you would get data about the button to publish the event
     *e.g: $(this).attr('id');
     */
    var nameOfButtonToPublishToEvent = "";
    ga('send', 'event', 'AddToCart', nameOfButtonToPublishToEvent);
});
```